# I cant connect to any Minecraft servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I can't connect to any Minecraft servers. It's not a firewall problem, other games work just fine. Every internet thing works except Minecraft. The Error it gives is either Disconnected, or Timed out.

I started up Minecraft as usual, but when I went to multiplayer, all of my saved servers were gone, and I could not connect to any servers at all. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

First try to relaunch Minecraft. That would fix a timeout issue.
If that doesn't work try to restart your router. That could reset any firewalls.
If that also dosn't work try to uninstall and reinstall Minecraft. 
I've had a problem once where a firewall was randomly set up so try to call your Internet Service Provider and see if there are any fire walls up. 
If all of this fails try Mojang Support.

https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new